# Insert bytecode by using ASM

Tags: java, runtime, bytecode

For example, In a subclass of MethodApdaptor

```
this.visitLdcInsn(className);
this.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
this.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC,
            "trace/profiler/Profile",
        "myMethod",
        "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

This piece of code works fine when writing in `visitCode()` and `visitInsn(int inst)`, but not working in `isitLocalVariable(name, desc, signature, start, end, index`)

It doesn't invoke myMethod().

Could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you add some more context on whats working and what is not? Ideally it would be a minimal example so that others can then reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method `visitLocalVariable(String name,
                      String desc,
                      String signature,
                      Label start,
                      Label end,
                      int index)`
is only for a local variable declaration and couldn't contain any code.